# infopath forms textbox word wrap chrome

Tags: google-chrome, textbox, infopath

The textbox in infopath form does not word-wrap the text in Chrome, but does it on IE? I have the multi-line setting checked on the text box. any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Upload a new css file to the “Style Library”.
2. File should contain the following:

textarea { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word
    !important; }

3. Go to Site Settings – Look and Feel – Master Page
   Set the Alternate CSS URL to point to the new CSS file that was added to the “Style Library”
4. Make sure to check “Reset all subsites…..”
5. Save and issue should be resolved for both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You will have to replace the Text Box Control with a **Rich Text Box Control** and reconfigure the setting in the new control. You can rename the Rich Text Box control with the same field name after you delete the Text Box Control.

This is just common to Chrome right now, but Edge and Safari, could make the same changes, so might as well make the change to the form. Common to all three is they won't update a form when you make a change to the form.

You can add a "Query a Data Connection Rule" to another control (like a button) and when you use that control it will contact the server and update the form. If you use the same control on different views in the same form it seems to continue working, trial and error on that.

I assume Edge and Safari will make changes similar to Chrome, so you might as well change the Text Box to Rich Text. I have 300 controls to change. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it two different ways. I wanted to target only specific forms rather than spend a lot of time on it or do it in master page, I created CSS using Code from solution #1, then dropped it in the site assets library. After that I edited the InfoPath Forms SharePoint Web Part page, added a Content Editor Web Part to the page at bottom after the InfoPath Form Web Part, linked the new Content Editor Web Part to the CSS file, changed the Content Editor Web Part settings to not be seen, etc. and saved the Content Editor Web Part, Then Saved the Web Part Page.

Another way I have done this is added a Rich Text Editor Control to the InfoPath Form, then hide the original Text Box Control and set the Text box control default value to that of the Rich Text Editor Control. Sometimes this is quicker and easier than redoing all the business logic, especially if you are trying to go to PowerApps and get away from InfoPath, don't waste as much time on it. Obviously the drawback is increasing the number of SharePoint fields and fields in the form as well.

Best Regards.
SG.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style.

```
textarea { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word !important; }
using script editor WP
```